# progress bar with upload file video with youtube api

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using youtube api for upload videos from my webpage.

This is my html form:

```
<form method="post" id="video_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/key=http://localhost:3000/en/id=4fc3af871d41c808f3000249" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="key=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
        <label for="Select_a_video">Select a video</label>
        <input type="file" name="yt_video_id" id="yt_video_id">
         <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload video" name="commit" id="submit_video_button" data-disable-with="Upload video" class="btn-large btn-primary">
         </div>
</form>
```

I use twitter bootstrap for design and I have this progress bar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var progress = setInterval(function() {
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    if ($bar.width()==400) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
    }
    $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
}, 800);

});​
```

you can see example in http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/68/

My problem is that the progress bar (progress) is not synchronized with the bytes or megabytes that has sent the file.

**I want the progress bar is synchronized with the bytes or megabytes that has sent the file and it displays correctly progress...**

How can I do it?

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't, unless you use AJAX/XHR to upload the file instead. If you leave it up to the browser, you will only know when the whole file has been uploaded.

Here's an XHR example:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/xhr-progress-and-richer-file-uploading-feedback/

However, I don't know whether the YouTube API supports this or not.